# Ansible Unarchive command causes error "Failed to find handler"

Tags: ansible

I operate AmazonLinux2 on EC2 using Ansible. However, when the Unarchive command is executed, the following error is displayed.

```
"Failed to find handler for \"/tmp/hoge.db.gz\".   
Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed.  
Command \"/usr/bin/unzip\" could not handle archive. Command \"/usr/bin/gtar\" could not handle archive."
```

The contents of PlayBook are as follows.

```
- name: Unarchive hoge
  become: yes
  unarchive:
    src: /tmp/hoge.db.gz
    dest: /root/fuga/
    remote_src: yes
```

Below is the information I have examined to identify the cause of the error.

- unarchive Requires Command

```sh
[root@ip- ~]# which gtar
/usr/bin/gtar
[root@ip- ~]# which unzip
/usr/bin/unzip
[root@ip- ~]# which zipinfo
/usr/bin/zipinfo
```

- PATH

```sh
- debug:
    var: ansible_env.PATH
```

```
"ansible_env.PATH": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unarchive` module cannot handle gzip files unless they are a compressed tar ball (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html).

You will need to use the `copy` module to first copy the gzip file, and then the `shell` module to decompress it using `gunzip`.

Example:

```
- copy:
    src: /tmp/hoge.db.gz
    dest: /root/fuga/hoge.db.gz
- shell: gunzip /root/fuga/hoge.db.gz
```

You may need to first install gunzip on the managed host

Answer (score 2):

It works if you use the extra_opts like so:

```
- name: Unarchive hoge
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: /tmp/hoge.db.gz
    dest: /root/fuga/
    remote_src: yes
    extra_opts:
     - '-z'
```

Tested with ansible 2.9.25 and python 3.6.8 on CentOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your archive file is indeed an archive. In my case I thought I downloaded tar.gz file, yet it was a pure html file.

Example: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.8.2/apache-zookeeper-3.8.2-bin.tar.gz

```
$ wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.8.2/apache-zookeeper-3.8.2-bin.tar.gz
$ file apache-zookeeper-3.8.2-bin.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines (785)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `gtar` to create the archive and not `tar`.

I was creating my archive files on RHEL 7 with `tar` and they worked fine with the `unarchive` module.

When I migrated to RHEL 8 and used the same `tar` script, I started getting this error. When I ran the same script with `gtar`, it worked fine.

I debugged the `ansible.modules.unarchive` module and behind the scenes, it runs this command:

`gtar --list -C <dest> <src>`

If that command returns error code 0, then it will work.